# Getting LNK 2019 errors in VS 2013 in directX 11 using C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker-errors, directx-11, lnk2019

Upon compilation of my program I am getting the following errors:

```
Error   59  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DXMatrixTranspose@8 referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall ColorShaderClass::SetShaderParameters(struct ID3D11DeviceContext *,struct D3DXMATRIX,struct D3DXMATRIX,struct D3DXMATRIX)" (?SetShaderParameters@ColorShaderClass@@AAE_NPAUID3D11DeviceContext@@UD3DXMATRIX@@11@Z)    D:\Programs\C++\DirectX 11\Tutorial 2\Tutorial 1\colorshaderclass.obj   Tutorial 1

Error   60  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DX11CompileFromFileW@44 referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall ColorShaderClass::InitializeShader(struct ID3D11Device *,struct HWND__ *,wchar_t *,wchar_t *)" (?InitializeShader@ColorShaderClass@@AAE_NPAUID3D11Device@@PAUHWND__@@PA_W2@Z) D:\Programs\C++\DirectX 11\Tutorial 2\Tutorial 1\colorshaderclass.obj   Tutorial 1

Error   61  error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   D:\Programs\C++\DirectX 11\Tutorial 2\Debug\Tutorial 1.exe  Tutorial 1
```

I have looked everywhere on the internet for an answer and have tried everything I found, does anyone know why I am getting these errors or how I can fix them?

Comment: You don't include enough information in your question for me to answer that, but take a look at [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/33499) first.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to link some libraries for the functions you use: [D3DXMatrixTranspose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204962(v=vs.85).aspx) and [D3DX11CompileFromFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476261(v=vs.85).aspx)

You can do this by adding the corresponding libraries to the Linker:

Project -> [ProjectName] Properties... -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies - then add these libraries:

- **D3DX10.lib**
- **D3DX11.lib**